# Removing background from td

Tags: jquery, css

I have a bunch of table rows being created dynamically.  they alternate background color.  I'm wondering if there's a way to remove the background color from the table data element in that table row.

```
<tr class='class1' id='row  value.roomID'> 
    <td>sBtn</td> 
    <td>value.jobName</td> 
    <td>value.woodType</td> 
    <td>value.finishColor</td> 
    <td>cBtn</td> 
</tr>
```

Basically I don't want the background behind the sBtn and cBtn.
I know I could add the class to the table data instead. I just don't want to cause I have the data being replaced several other times in my code with different jquery events, and it's much easier to keep the table row color and replace the table data inside.

Anyone know of a good way to this.

Comment: is the background a colour or an image?  do you want the background of the `<td>` to be white?

Comment: It's just a color

Comment: I would prefer to just remove the background, so that it's transparent

Comment: have you tried `td{background-color: transparent}`?

Comment: td{background-color: transparent} Doesn't Work. I have a button inside the table data, the button doesn't take up the entire space and what's behind the button is the same color as the rest of the tr

Comment: you want button with same color as tr? or transparent button?

Comment: If you're background-color is on the `tr` then no, you can't remove it per td as it will fall-back to the tr colour, however you could simply change your css so that the background colour is on the `td`s instead:  `table.class1 tr td { background-color: red }`  then you can change it or remove it per td as required.

Comment: The alternative is to *set* the td colour to the same colour as what's *behind* the table - so it looks like it's transparent.  Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qjybbo25/

Comment: this is what I'm getting https://codepen.io/timallred/pen/VWKZqx and this is what I want https://codepen.io/timallred/pen/dRpbQm

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use td:[first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) & td:[last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

```css
.class1 {
   background-color: lightgray;
}
.class2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
tr {
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  text-align: auto;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 75%;
}

tbody tr td:first-child,
tbody tr td:last-child {
   background:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Start</td>
        <td>Job Name</td>
        <td>Wood Type</td>
        <td>Finish Color</td>
        <td>Start</td>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
   <tr class='class1' id='row  value.roomID'> 
    <td>sBtn</td> 
    <td>value.jobName</td> 
    <td>value.woodType</td> 
    <td>value.finishColor</td> 
    <td>cBtn</td> 
   </tr>
   
   <tr class='class2' id='row  value.roomID'> 
    <td>sBtn</td> 
    <td>value.jobName</td> 
    <td>value.woodType</td> 
    <td>value.finishColor</td> 
    <td>cBtn</td> 
   </tr>
   
  </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to apply classes to all the `td`, you can target the `td` through the `tr` class.

```
.class1 td{background:red}

.class1 td:first-child,
.class1 td:last-child{background:transparent;}
```

---

Updated example

```css
.background1 td{background:lightgray}
.background1 td:first-child,
.background1 td:last-child{background:transparent;}

.background2 td{background:lightblue}
.background2 td:first-child,
.background2 td:last-child{background:transparent;}


tr {
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  text-align: auto;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 75%;
}
```

```html
  <table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Start</td>
        <td>Job Name</td>
        <td>Wood Type</td>
        <td>Finish Color</td>
        <td>Start</td>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr class="background1">
        <td><button>Start</button></td>
        <td>Some Job</td>
        <td>Some Wood</td>
        <td>Some Color</td>
        <td><button>Start</button></td>
      </tr>
    <tr class="background2">Some Color 2>
        <td><button>Start</button></td>
        <td>Some Job 2</td>
        <td>Some Wood 2</td>
        <td>Some Color 2</td>
        <td><button>Start</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this goal with jquery by selecting all columns except first and last `$("tbody td:not(:nth-child(4n+1))")` this selection is correct for 5 columns. `4n+1` can change according to column count.

```
(ColumnCount-1)n +1
```

```js
$("tbody td:not(:nth-child(4n+1))").addClass("class1");
```

```css
.class1 {
   background-color: lightblue;
}

tr {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Start</td>
        <td>Job Name</td>
        <td>Wood Type</td>
        <td>Finish Color</td>
        <td>Start</td>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
   <tr id='row1'> 
    <td>sBtn</td> 
    <td>value.jobName</td> 
    <td>value.woodType</td> 
    <td>value.finishColor</td> 
    <td>cBtn</td> 
   </tr>
   
   <tr id='row2'> 
    <td>sBtn2</td> 
    <td>value.jobName2</td> 
    <td>value.woodType2</td> 
    <td>value.finishColor2</td> 
    <td>cBtn2</td> 
   </tr>
   
   
  </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```